# What is the W3C stance on sending GET params in a POST request?

Tags: php, ajax, http

The title pretty much sums it up. Many web languages support sending/receiving URL encoded GET parameters in POST requests. Is this an acceptable practice per the HTTP standard?

Comment: This isn't a canonical answer by any means, but I think as far as HTTP is concerned, the "GET parameters" are just part of the URL string, and have no intrinsic meaning. The practice of mixing hard-coded query string parameters in HTML forms (with GET or POST methods set), and their behaviour under CGI, might be covered by some other standard or advice, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as **HTTP** is concerned, there is no such thing as a "GET parameter". A URL identifies a *resource*, and you can perform various actions on that resource, including `GET`ting it, and `POST`ing data to it. Identifying a resource as `https://api.example.com/item?id=42` and performing a `POST` request to update that item is perfectly valid from that point of view. It might well be used in a so-called "RESTful API", although more often a dynamic URL such as `https://api.example.com/item/42` would probably be preferred.

The reason the query string part of a URL is sometimes thought of as "GET parameters" is because it is the part generated when you submit a form in **HTML** using `method="get"`. A form can have an `action` URL with a query-string already attached, and a `method` stating that the data should be sent to that URL with a `POST` request. Having an existing query string and a `method` of `"get"` leads to the browser having to decide exactly how to combine the two, but a query-string + "post" presents no conflict.

Finally, the page you are submitting to will need to actually process your data. Many **simple CGI libraries** will merge together variables parsed from the query string and from a POST submitted form. This may be what you want, or you may want to treat them as two separate "namespaces". PHP, for instance, allows both approaches, providing `$_GET` (query-string variables, regardless of HTTP method) and `$_POST` (POSTed form data) as well as `$_REQUEST`, which combines the two in a configurable way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specification - it is allowed:

```
Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF

Request-URI    = "*" | absoluteURI | abs_path | authority

absoluteURI   = scheme ":" ( hier_part | opaque_part )

hier_part     = ( net_path | abs_path ) [ "?" query ]
```

References:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

Answer (score 0):

Sending parameters vis POST [in url-encoded format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is not only allowed, it is [the default for encoding POST data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype). To quote the spect for HTML forms:

> enctype = content-type [CI]
>   This attribute specifies the content type used to submit the form to the server (when the value of method is "post"). The default value for this attribute is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The value "multipart/form-data" should be used in combination with the INPUT element, type="file".

Comment: Of course it makes sense.  `POST /items?id=50` might post some info to item 50, for example.  If the id has meaning outside of the data you want to post, it actually makes *more* sense to have it in the URL, IMO.

Comment: Query parameters in the URL are sometimes called "GET parameters" because they're almost always used in GET requests -- they're about the only universally-supported way of sending information via GET.  (Not all APIs let you specify cookies, fewer let you set custom headers, and very few let you include a body.)

Comment: @cHao: Yes, you're right, thanks. I've removed that part. This should still be useful enough as an answer, that url-encoding is allowed and the default to transmit data via POST.